# IntelliJ Ruby syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

I am having some issues with getting IntelliJ to properly recognize my Ruby / Rails application syntax.

Screenshot here:
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/4a3072c9-0439-4d31-aa16-85796d1a011a/ed4017710a5dcf700396c751011dae74

I have the Ruby plugin installed. I also have the Rails gem and other gems installed, but no go.

Any idaes?

Comment: [Configuring Colors and Fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html). Just select **Ruby**, change highlight and disable effects.

Comment: Wish this had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

(The question was posted a while ago but I want to make @mattalxndr's wish come true :-) )

This looks like an issue with the *Hash notation* and not color highlighting.
The wiggly red line indicates that IntelliJ is not recognizing the `{symbol: "value"}` syntax. In contrast, `{:jobs => @jobs}` is valid on the same line.

This syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9.

**Solution:** Go to the SDK tab in the Project Structure window and make sure that you are using ruby 1.9 or higher.

[image]

BTW, you can switch between the two notations by placing the cursor on the symbol and invoking the "Show intention action" function (in OSX the keys are ⎇⏎).

[image]